# In performance test if we need to go back to Home page to access next link then should Home page request be included after every request

Tags: jmeter

For example : Home page have below links

a,b,c,d
While recording performance script will click on a and navigate to respective  page . Now to access link b I need to go back to Home page . should Home page be included in after every request ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

1. Open Home page
2. Store all links into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)
3. Iterate all the links using either [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) or directly use them in further [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers "Path" if your test scenario is different.

Comment: if in test plan my first request if www.test.com/a/ and second is www.test.com/b/ then for the second request what should be added in  Referrer of HTTP Header as Home page URL or first request url ? Please advice.

Comment: If in this case my first request if for Home page (www.test.com/) , second if for link a (www.test.com/a/) and third request of for link b (www.test.com/b/).

Comment: continuation to second comment : in third request for link b (www.test.com/b/) what should be  Referrer of HTTP Header as www.test.com/ or www.test.com/a/  ?

Comment: If there are 5 links on the home page (a,b, c,d, e, f) and 3 links (g,h,i) are accessible via Next arrow .
In script if first click on link a from Home page then I can see refer as Home page url in script . While doing this by CSV data file I cant see refer so Is it the right approach to perform load test in scenarios like this